# A doubt related to Sound

Tags: energy, waves, energy-conservation, acoustics, conservation-laws

According to laws of conservation of energy energy can neither be created nor be destroyed. We all know that sound is energy. But according to law of conservation of energy- sound can neither be created not be destroyed. Then how can humans make sound ?

Comment: The same argument could be made for light, electricity, movement, ...

Answer (score 3):

> According to laws of conservation of energy energy can neither be created nor be destroyed

This is fine. In other words, if something gains energy, that energy has to come from somewhere. If something loses energy, that energy has to go somewhere else.

> We all know that sound is energy.

This is not really true, or at least it is not precise. It is true that you need energy to start a sound wave, but sound itself is not energy. Just like how it takes energy to accelerate your car, but you wouldn't say your car is energy. You can also say that air molecules moving due to the sound wave have energy, but sound is not energy in itself.

> But according to law of conservation of energy- sound can neither be created not be destroyed. Then how can humans make sound ?

So bringing it all together. We use energy to produce sound. This is our energy conservation.$^*$ Just because something didn't have energy and now it has energy does not mean the energy was created out of nothing.

---

$^*$ I won't go into the biology of explaining where the energy comes from (I'm sure a quick Google search can give you this information).

Comment: @ALEN If the answer is sufficient, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

No one tells that "sound energy" will never change to other type of energy - what about transformation of it to heat?

Answer (score 0):

Atomic transitions and reactions create light. Sun sends light . Plants photosynthesise using this light . Animals eat plants. You eat animals or plants. And then use the energy of food to vibrate your vocal muscles which in turn vibrate the air  this creating sound . The sound waves disperse in the surrounding the reflect and propagate and finally all their energy is converted to heat or any other form. It's very hard and virtually immpossible to find exceptions to law of  energy conservation . So don't try ...Use time efficiently